# MS Access Query Multiple Groups and Criteria Greatest-N Per-Group

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

Okay guys, I am at my limit with this thing. I have a query that is referring to a separate actual attendance table query (qryEventDates) and a scheduled attendance table (Attendance Schedule). The query so far works up until the point that the student (EventID) has multiple schedules (Schedule Effective Date). I entered a criteria to limit the output to just the schedules that are <= to the attendance date (EventDate), but once the student has more than one schedule it shows both the old and the new schedule. (See the image link).

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vz1Z.png)

I am basically trying to get it to only show the attendance schedule that should be active on that day for each student. I have tried numerous queries (Top queries and the like) and other methods, but this is the closest I've been so far. See the MS Access SQL query below:

`SELECT q.EventID, q.EventDate, s.[Schedule Effective Date], s.SunOC, s.SunDE, s.MonOC, s.MonDE, s.TueOC, s.TueDE, s.WedOC, s.WedDE, s.ThuOC, s.ThuDE, s.FriOC, s.FriDE, s.SatOC, s.SatDE
FROM [Attendance Schedule] AS s RIGHT JOIN qryEventDates AS q ON s.Schedule_FK_Student_ID = q.EventID
WHERE (((s.[Schedule Effective Date])<=[EventDate]))
ORDER BY q.EventID, q.EventDate;`

I am open to changing the setup around if need be...this is the last thing I'm trying to work out. Please go easy on me, I am self taught and I mostly know Access as an end user and not as a database programmer.

Let me know if any more information is needed. Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making an inference, but would something like this be of help:

```
SELECT q.StudentID, q.EventDate, s.[Schedule Effective Date]
FROM qryEventDates AS q INNER JOIN [Attendance Schedule] AS s 
ON q.StudentID = s.Student_ID
WHERE (((s.[Schedule Effective Date])=
(SELECT MAX([Schedule Effective Date]) FROM [Attendance Schedule] A 
WHERE A.[Student_ID]=s.[Student_ID] AND A.[Schedule Effective Date] <= [EventDate])))
ORDER BY q.EventDate
```

Results for first month:

```
StudentID   EventDate   Schedule Effective Date
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-19  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-20  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-21  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-22  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-23  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-24  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-25  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-26  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-27  2016-01-19
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-28  2016-01-28
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-29  2016-01-28
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-30  2016-01-28
ST-AAR0000  2016-01-31  2016-01-28
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I'm just in the beginning phases of things right now, but this is what I needed to work everything out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The EventID is the StudentID?
What is the difference between the [Schedule Effective Date] and [Event Date]?
I suggest to explain in words what you want to solve ... maybe a different DB design will help.